# Logging request and response values for a WCF request on the server

Tags: wcf

I can see similar questions to this on here but nothing specifically the same.

I have a WCF public API that clients can query with an API key. So something like:

```
string GetDataForRegion(string apiKey, int regionId);
```

I need to be able to log these requests along with the data sent back to the client. I can get the response using an **IDispatchMessageInspector** but I can't see where I can get the request parameters.

I can see this is possible using an **IParameterInspector** but then how do I tie the request and reponse together?

Ideally, I'm wanting to write something like this to the logs (in a DB):

*DateTime, APIKey, MethhodCalled, Parameters, Response*

Sp, using the sample above, it'd be:

*2012-04-24-15-52-11, myapikey, GetDataForRegion, { regionId: 1 }, [response data]*

Is this possible within anything built in with WCF?

Thanks,

K

Comment: Can you not just use WCF tracing for this, or does it need to be some custom form of logging?

Comment: I had a look at tracing but the output needs to go into a format that can be easily viewed and queried. So, probably going to need to write to a database. Parsing the trace logs into a database is on my "hope I don't have to do that" list of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IParameterInspector` is what you want. On the server side, the `BeforeCall` method is called before your user code is invoked, and you are able to return a state value from this method (typically this would be a `Guid` but it can be anything.) Once your service has run and produced a return value, `AfterCall` will be called with that same state value from the matching `BeforeCall`. On the client side, it works basically the same way, except the calls happen before and after the round-trip to the server.

In your case, it would probably be easiest to log the information in stages. Insert the request data into the database during the inbound call, and return some unique identifier (identity field, timestamp, whatever) from the call. On the return trip, update the matching record with the response data. This also gives you a quick way to see how long a call took, and if any calls failed to return, for example.

Here is a short introduction to how these work, with code:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/28/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx

You can also use `IDispatchMessageInspector` for the same purpose, and it works basically the same way, but you have to tear apart the `Message` object yourself; the parameter inspectors are probably a much better option. Message inspectors are more powerful, and seem to be more commonly used, even for things where there are "simpler" options; see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

Comment: Looks like the best way to go. I'd been looking at something similar and populating the response from IDispatchMessageInspector but was having issues with getting the data only (and config would be a pain). Didn't realise the data was available in the IParameterInspector so that saves a lot of time. Thanks!